# Woocommerce - Return product attribute in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce 2.4, I edited /loop/title.php to include a product attribute, like this:

```
<h3 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php $versionvalues get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist');

foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) {
      echo $versionvalue->name;
} ?></h3>
```

In Woocommerce 2.5, title.php is no longer used. It is built into a function. I am having real difficulty returning the product attribute by editing my functions.php in my child theme.

I have been trying to use this code, but the `foreach` always throws an error.

```
if (  ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title' ) ) {
    /**
     * Show the product title in the product loop. By default this is an H3.
     */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
        echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
        echo '<h3 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">' .  $versionvalues get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist');

        echo foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) {
             echo $versionvalue->name;
        echo } '</h3>';
    }
}
```

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is messed up.. try something like this... do not edit the plugin... add this code to your `functions.php` in your theme...

```
function my_template_loop_product_title(){
    global $product;
    echo '<h3 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">';
    $versionvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_artist');

    foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) {
         echo $versionvalue->name;
    }
    echo '</h3>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

Comment: This works well, but it adds pa_artist to the beginning. Before I added this, it showed title and price, now it shows pa_artist, title and price. I want to show title, pa_artist and then price.